# MDX Using multiple date dimensions

Tags: mdx, mondrian

What I want to do is generate a report containing an overview of gains and losses (of contracts). For example:

```
Year | contract_gains | contract_losses
_______________________________________
2015 |             10 |               2 
2016 |             15 |               4
```

Showing the gains is quite easy because I can just count distinct contracts (which is the aggregator for the measure value) with a start period.

```
SELECT
  {[contract_start_date].[year].MEMBERS} 
    ON ROWS,
  {[Measures].[value]}
    ON COLUMNS
FROM Cube
```

Showing the losses seperately is also easy because I can do the same with the second date dimension.

```
SELECT
  {[contract_end_date].[year].MEMBERS} 
    ON ROWS,
  {[Measures].[value]}
    ON COLUMNS
FROM Cube
```

But what I want to do is generate a report containing both of the values in a single report. Sadly I have no idea how I can do this.

Comment: I think you can achieve this by using view. You can create a view to make gain and loss together

Comment: Hi Vels4j, I don't know what you mean with a view in the context of a mondrian cube. Could you explain what you mean with a view?

Answer (score 0):

A little slow method, going cell by cell. Does this work for you -

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].contract_losses AS
    (
    GENERATE 
            (
        [contract_start_date].[year].CURRENTMEMBER,
        FILTER
            (
              [contract_end_date].[year].MEMBERS,
              CStr([contract_start_date].[year].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE) = CStr([contract_end_date].[year].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE)
            )
             ).ITEM(0)
        ,
        [Measures].[value]
    )

MEMBER [Measures].contract_gains AS
[Measures].[value]

SELECT
  NON EMPTY {[contract_start_date].[year].MEMBERS} 
    ON ROWS,
  {[Measures].contract_gains, [Measures].contract_losses}
    ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
```